# When I “Pull to refresh”, How I clean the Cache? With Ionic Framework and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem, I'm using a JSON coming from an external server, but when I do "Pull to refresh" or when I open the application, displays the same information I downloaded the first time the application is opened. It may be that the JSON is being stored in the cache and therefore not update? For if when I go to on-refresh = "doRefresh ()" and called another JSON, (the first time I do), update, but re-enter the application I load the information from the first JSON and if I want update, showing me the information I also downloaded the first time. This will fix manually deleting the application data, but it is not the best way ...

This is my services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('NotasService', ['$http',
    function ($http) {

        var items_nota = [];
        var items_nota_array;

        return {

            all: function () {
                return $http.get('http://192.168.1.0:8100/wp-json/posts?filter[post_status]=publish&filter[posts_per_page]=30')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  console.log("**** SUCCESS ****");
                  console.log(status);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  console.log("**** ERROR ****");
                  console.log(status);
                })
                .then(function(response){
                  console.log("**** THEN ****");

                        items_nota = response;
                        return items_nota;


                  }
                )
            },
            get: function (notaId) {
                // Simple index lookup
                var pepe = parseInt(notaId);

                var ESTO = 0;

                var addToArray = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < items_nota.length; i++) {
                    if (items_nota[i].id == pepe) {
                        addToArray = false;
                        ESTO = i;
                    }
                }


                return items_nota[ESTO];
            }

        }
}])
```

This is my controller.js..

```
.controller('ActulidadCtrl', function ($q, $scope, NotasService, $timeout) {

        var items_nota;

        NotasService.all().then(function (data) {
            $scope.items_nota = data;
        })

        //Pull tu refresh
        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            console.log('Actualizando!');
            $timeout(function () {
                //NotasService.loadData().then(function (data) {
                NotasService.all().then(function (data) {
                    $scope.items_nota = data;
                })

                //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

            });

        };
    })
```

Thanks! And Happy New Year!

**UPDATE:** solved the problem was in the server side cache

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: I can't get update information, even if the JSON (on the web) if this update, the information displayed in the application is the same as the first connection to be made to open

Comment: **UPDATE:** solved the problem was in the server side cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with GET query:

```
http://192.168.1.0:8100/wp-json/posts?filter[post_status]=publish&filter[posts_per_page]=30
```

Please check if this query is returning same posts event if you add new data.You can make sample http query using tools like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/).

> post_status and posts_per_page are constant.

Please check. Good luck!!

Comment: I tried what you said, and is updated on the Postman, the problem remains within the application does not update the information

Comment: Can you put `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');` in the `NotasService.all().then(function (data) {
                    $scope.items_nota = data;
                })`,

Comment: @gabfiocchi I've having the same problem. How did you solve this issue?